# Program crashes while comparing pointers to NULL

Tags: c++, class, pointers, tree

```
 template<class item_type>
 struct node{
     item_type x;
     node<item_type> *left;
     node<item_type> *right;
     //functions
 };

 template<class item_type, class param>
 class Tree{
        node<item_type> *root;
    public:
        item_type Get_Item(param item);
        void Add_Item(item_type item);
        void Delete_Item(item_type item);

        //more functions

        Tree();
};


template<class item_type, class param>
Tree<item_type, param>::Tree()
{
    this->root = new node<item_type>;

    this->root->left=NULL;
    this->root->right=NULL;

}
```

ADD ITEM:

```
void Tree<item_type, param>::Add_Item(item_type item)
{

    node<item_type> newItem;
    newItem.x = item;
    node<item_type> *cur = root;
    node<item_type> *prev;

    if(cur->x==NULL)
        cur->x=item;

    int ifGreater;
    while(cur->left!=NULL || cur->right!=NULL)
    {
        if(item<cur->x)
        {
            ifGreater = 0;
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->left;
        }
        else
        {
            ifGreater = 1;
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->right;
        }
    }
    if(ifGreater==1)
        prev->right = &newItem;
    if(ifGreater==0)
        prev->left = &newItem;
}
```

Problem occurs here in this function at the `cout<<1`;

```
template<class item_type, class param>
    void Tree<item_type, param>::Delete_Item(item_type item)
    {
        node<item_type> *cur = root;
        node<item_type> *prev;

        int ifGreater;
        if(cur==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
            return;
        }

        while(cur!= NULL && (cur->left!=NULL || cur->right!=NULL))
        {   
            cout<<1; //crash occurs RIGHT before here as 1 is never printed
            if(item<cur->x)
            {
                //do something   
            }                              
        }
```

The problem occurs before the `cout<<1` and after the declaration of `int ifGreater;` The `cout` is merely just to test where it runs and where it stops running.
I run this function using a call to

```
int main()
{
     Tree<int,int> theTree;
     theTree.Add_Item(1); //so the tree isn't empty
     theTree.Delete_Item(1);
}
```

NOTE: The program doesn't even get past the first iteration, the improper handling of memory (which is fixed) was not the issue of this specific error.

Comment: how did you initialize root?

Comment: @pippin1289 in the constructor `root = new node<item_type>`

Comment: At the very least you want to bail out of the loop after `delete`ing the current node `cur`. You probably also need to patch up the pointers pointing to this node, probably before `delete`ing it.

Comment: It should help to sit down with a piece of paper and think through how it's meant to work.  You should handle root == NULL, and in addition to Dietmar's advice, you should bail out (break/return) when "not found".

Comment: It doesn't get up to that point, but thank you @DietmarKühl fixed :)

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help you without a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), or at least a complete one.

Comment: It might help to check the `node<item_type> *` pointer `cur` or `root` for NULL before trying to access the `left` and `right` nodes through the pointers.

Comment: `cur` itself might be `NULL`. If you try to dereference a null pointer (i.e. `(NULL)->var`), your program will crash.

Comment: @ali @santa I had it checked, in `while(cur!= NULL && (cur->left!=NULL || cur->right!=NULL))` Also, I made sure it wasn't null in another function that put a value into the root before calling this function.

Comment: Your example isn't complete and self-contained enough for us to reproduce. You'll received better help following Beta's suggestion. Failing that, step through your code using a debugger and see where exactly the crash happens.

Comment: @greatwolf I'm honestly not sure how to make it more complete and self contained. It compiles and I show where the crash happens. In an objective standpoint here, what would help make this more complete?

Comment: Show the calling code or a simple minimal test that uses your above class that still exhibits the crash. Remove any code that isn't irrelevant of course.

Comment: @greatwolf I'm not sure if any of this is better. I show my class and the relevant function declarations, the call and the function implementation up to the crash and note specifically where the crash occurs via comment.

Comment: Can you also show the `Add_Item` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in the following piece of code:

```
template <class item_type, class param>
void Tree<item_type, param>::Add_Item(item_type item)
{
    node<item_type> newItem;
    // ...
    if (ifGreater == 1)
        prev->right = &newItem;
    if (ifGreater == 0)
        prev->left = &newItem;       
}
```

Above, `newItem` is a *local* variable and you're keeping a pointer to that local well after it expires when `Add_Item` exits. This is likely the reason for the crash.

Additionally, you never initialized `ifGreater` or `node<item_type> *prev;`. Again, this results in more undefined behavior when this gets executed:

```
    if (ifGreater == 1)
        prev->right = &newItem;
    if (ifGreater == 0)
        prev->left = &newItem;
```

You likely end up deferencing some random piece of memory. This is because there's no guarantee your `while` loop executes, eg. Consider the case where both `left` and `right` is `NULL`.

Comment: I had a check beforehand to check if `cur==NULL` or in `Add_Item()`'s case when `cur->x==NULL` since there should always be a `cur`
Also I thought I was allowed to initialize the mentioned variables in branches.

Comment: `cur-x` is the payload, it's the data you're storing. Comparing it to `NULL` isn't really correct unless you're storing a pointer type.

Comment: @SemicolonExpected While the condition of `cur == NULL` is false, it may point to an invalid memory location though because you have once point it to a temporary variable w/c cause the pointer to dangled when that temporary variable goes out of scope. See [Dangling Pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Comment: I think I fixed the issue with newItem, by instead making it a pointer to new node ie `node<item_type> *newItem = new node<item_type>`, I'm not sure if the same problem still exists with this, but it seems to be working. I also initialized prev to cur to be safe.

Comment: @SemicolonExpected note that your original `Delete_Item` method still has issues. If you just delete a given node then the link to that entire branch will be lost and you'll leak memory.